# tailwind.config,js custom colours not changing

Tags: react-native, colors, tailwind-css, config

Hello Everyone I am facing an issue with a **tailwind** **css** custom colors, I defined some colors but they are not changing means I have some custom colors and they work fine at first but when I change the value of any of the color the changes does not get reflected in my app and I am using react native for this project with **nativewind** and **tailwindcss,** I also tried to re-run the app but still no changes

**Tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  // './<custom-folder>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  // darkMode: true,
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // 'mainCol': '#00FFAE',
      "theme": {
        'mainDarkCol': '#000',
        'mainLightCol': '#CEFBE3',
        'buttonBg': '#5DD0E1',
        'buttonText': '#34B7CB',
      },
      'navBg': {
        'from': 'rgba(5, 119, 98, 1)',
        'to': 'rgba(7, 221, 137, 1)'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**Current response of the app**

[image]

After changing the **mainLightCol** to something else like black I still get the same color as the image shows above even I tried to stop the react-native server and re-run it but that also didn't work.

This happens with all the custom colors not only with **mainLightCol**.

Does anyone have any solution

And also for the starting time I was using the **colors** in the **extended dictonary** but then I saw on the github someone says to use it in **theme** dictonary but both of the approach does not solve my issue.

Maybe it is called **extended dictonary** if not please tell me what it is called. :)

I tried to change the custom colors in the config js file of tailwind and expected it to change the color of my app but it stick with the old color.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions:

**Bad Solution**

Update your color name and do a global find/replace. (ex: change `"theme": {` to `"newTheme": {`).

**Proper Solution**

Clear expo cache: `expo start -c`. This results in a much slower start up, so I made a "clear cache" script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "expo start",
  "clearCache": "expo start -c",
```

`npm run clearCache` or `yarn clearCache`